# The set $\{f\in X:\int_{0}^{1}fdx=0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the space $C[0,1]$ with its usual sup-norm topology .Consider the set The set $$S=\{f\in X:\int_{0}^{1}fdx=0\}$$ Then the set $S$ is

$A.$ Compact.

$B.$ Connected.

$C.$ Closed.

$D.$ Open.

$E.$ Dense in $X.$

According to me since the map $f\rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}f$ is continuous so the set $S$ is clearly closed . Again $S$ is convex so connected. I don't know about compactness and denseness. Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider the functions $f_n = n \sin (2\pi x)$ which are all in $S$.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes it gives that that set $S$ is unbounded...Thanks...

Comment: Note that $f\in S, g\in S \Rightarrow f+g\in S$, so it's a (closed) subspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. $S$ is a non-zero linear subspace of $C[0,1]$, hence it's unbounded and non compact.

D. $S$ is connected and closed, non-empty and not equal to $C[0,1]$, hence it's not open.

E. $S$ is closed and not equal to $C[0,1]$, hence it's not dense.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B(0,n) = \{f \in X : \|f\| < n\}$, then $\{B(0,n)\}$ covers $S$ but does not admit a finite subcover. (see John Hughes' comment)

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and let $f \in X$ be such that $f\ge 0$ and $\int f\,dx = 2\epsilon$. If $S$ is dense in $X$ then we can find $g \in S$ such that $\|f - g\| < \epsilon$. But then $$\int_0^1f\,dx = \int_0^1 f - g\,dx \le \epsilon.$$